# convert point to a grid in R

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-sp

I have a latitude and longitude

```
locs <- structure(list(Latitude = 0.176094639, Longitude = 117.4955225), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to convert this into a square polygon grid with dimension of 5 km X 5 km and save the shapefile. I can't seem to find a function in R to do this and wondering if anyone has done
similar work?

Comment: Are these the centre points of the grid?

Comment: They are point locations. What my end goal is to create a buffer around the point and examine if a particular highway passes through the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the point you provided is the center of the grid you want,

- make the point an sf object
- buffer it by 2.5km
- get the bounding box of the buffer
- make a grid (10x10 used below)
- write the shapefile(commented out)

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse) # pipe & plotting

locs <- structure(list(Latitude = 0.176094639, Longitude = 117.4955225), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

# Make the point an sf object
locs_sf <- locs %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude')) %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326)

# get the bounding box of a 2500m buffered circle around the point
box <- st_buffer(locs_sf, 2500) %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()

# make a 10x10 grid of the bounding box
grid <- st_make_grid(box, n = c(10,10))

# Use st_write() to write your shapefile
#st_write(grid, '/path/to/file.shp')

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = locs_sf, color = 'red', size = 5) + 
  geom_sf(data = grid, fill = NA, color = 'black')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you. How can I merge all grids instead of having a 10X10 individual grids. I was expecting a single grid the centroid of which is the given point

Comment: You're welcome.  In the above code the `box` object is a single square (~5km x ~5km) with the point at the center.  Just skip the `st_make_grid` step.