# Create grid from list of spatial coordinates of grid centroids in R

Tags: r, grid, spatial, centroid

I have a list of spatial coordinates that correspond to 5184 grid centroids. I would like to create a grid that has 5184 cells. I am using `st_make_grid`. I think my problem comes from `cellsize` because I am not sure how to define it. This is the data I am using:

```
head(df_sf)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -74.29167 ymin: 40.89167 xmax: -73.75 ymax: 41
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  avg.dday30                   geometry
1  30.439710       POINT (-74.29167 41)
2  29.280088       POINT (-74.21667 41)
3 190.002556 POINT (-74.06667 40.99167)
4   9.808251 POINT (-73.76667 40.89167)
5   8.892234 POINT (-73.75833 40.89167)
```

and code:

```
...
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords=c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)
grid <- st_make_grid(df_sf,
                     cellsize=c(diff(st_bbox(df_sf)[c(1,3)]),diff(st_bbox(df_sf)[c(2,4)]))/c(71,71),
                     offset = st_bbox(df_sf)[c("xmin", "ymin")]-c(cellsize/2,cellsize/2),
                     what="polygons",
                     square=TRUE
)
```

EDIT: In this case I manually estimate the 71 and then manually pick the offset to make sure the cendroids are at the center of the grid cell: how do I find it automatically ?

Comment: Could you add a small subset of spatial coordinates using the output of `dput(your_dataset)` that correspond to say 25 (a 5x5) grid centroids to make a reproducible minimal example?

Comment: What was the resolution/cell size of the original grid? You could st_buffer your points by that, which increases your bbox, and fingers crossed, both takes your out of guesstimating bbox and lands your points back to desired centroids akin to [point to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607107/convert-point-to-a-grid-in-r), though I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Hi Chris, the original grid is 800m by 800m. But I don't want to set ```cellsize=800``` because that would involve changing the CRS which I don't want.  I'll look into the option with point to grid thanks ! 
Hi Peter, I've added using head(df_sf) hopefully that works, because but the output of df_sf() is too long

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create grid around points (centroids) using sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800327/create-grid-around-points-centroids-using-sf)